# Time between process runs is occasionally too long, how can I set a maximum time?

Tags: raspberry-pi, c, process-management, real-time

I am using a raspberry pi to grab data through a SPI port. Attached to the SPI port is a PIC, programmed so that it samples on an A/D at 12.8kHz, and stores the samples in a 256 long buffer. (to cope with linux process pause and runs).

I have a linux program that reads the SPI and writes to a file. a couple of times per second I am getting missing data, I believe because linux is taking too long to return to my C program.

I understand that Linux (Raspbian) is not real-time and a process/program can be interrupted at any time, and that is why I am using a buffer in the PIC, to ride through these interruptions.

The problem is that sometimes the delay where the program waits is too large, and so I am missing some of the data. This happens maybe once every few seconds:

**I would like suggestions for reducing the time, or at least setting a maximum time between process run time slices.**

I have tried running with a nice level of -15 and -20.

**Is there a way to reduce time slices?**

**Is there a memory disk on Raspbian that I can try writing my file to, incase it is the writing of the file that is causing it?**

Here is some output from top:

```
top - 14:01:23 up  2:25,  3 users,  load average: 1.91, 2.09, 2.18
Tasks:  76 total,   1 running,  75 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.6 us, 28.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 63.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    185732 total,   105708 used,    80024 free,    21112 buffers
KiB Swap:   102396 total,        0 used,   102396 free,    43916 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                  
  353 root      20   0     0    0    0 D  15.3  0.0  17:01.87 spi0                                                     
13296 root       5 -15  2652 1468 1344 D  12.1  0.8   0:09.21 a.out                                                    
13386 pi        20   0  4708 2500 2064 R   1.6  1.3   0:00.40 top                                                      
 4707 pi        20   0  4176 2572 1976 S   1.0  1.4   2:48.66 watch                                                    
11547 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.6  0.0   0:03.59 kworker/u2:1                                             
   16 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:05.60 kworker/0:1                                              
 2524 pi        20   0  9288 3296 2708 S   0.3  1.8   0:00.62 sshd                                                     
12448 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:02.98 kworker/u2:4                                             
    1 root      20   0  2168 1368 1260 S   0.0  0.7   0:02.22 init                                                     
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                 
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:06.88 ksoftirqd/0                                              
    5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00
```

I can see from top that the a.out and spi0 process are using the most CPU time, but they are not maxing it out. Here you can see my process has a nice of -15.

**Maybe one of the processes that is running is interfering?** Here are my running processes, a.out is my SPI reading program.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/frd/src/raspi/xcodefrd $ ps -ae
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:02 init
    2 ?        00:00:00 kthreadd
    3 ?        00:00:07 ksoftirqd/0
    5 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:0H
    7 ?        00:00:00 khelper
    8 ?        00:00:00 kdevtmpfs
    9 ?        00:00:00 netns
   10 ?        00:00:00 perf
   11 ?        00:00:00 khungtaskd
   12 ?        00:00:00 writeback
   13 ?        00:00:00 crypto
   14 ?        00:00:00 bioset
   15 ?        00:00:00 kblockd
   16 ?        00:00:06 kworker/0:1
   17 ?        00:00:00 rpciod
   18 ?        00:00:00 kswapd0
   19 ?        00:00:00 fsnotify_mark
   20 ?        00:00:00 nfsiod
   26 ?        00:00:00 kthrotld
   27 ?        00:00:00 VCHIQ-0
   28 ?        00:00:00 VCHIQr-0
   29 ?        00:00:00 VCHIQs-0
   30 ?        00:00:00 iscsi_eh
   31 ?        00:00:00 dwc_otg
   32 ?        00:00:00 DWC Notificatio
   34 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:2
   35 ?        00:00:01 mmcqd/0
   36 ?        00:00:00 VCHIQka-0
   37 ?        00:00:00 SMIO
   38 ?        00:00:00 deferwq
   40 ?        00:00:00 jbd2/mmcblk0p6-
   41 ?        00:00:00 ext4-rsv-conver
  156 ?        00:00:00 udevd
  286 ?        00:00:00 udevd
  293 ?        00:00:00 udevd
  321 ?        00:00:00 cfg80211
  353 ?        00:18:14 spi0
  411 ?        00:00:00 kworker/0:1H
 1792 ?        00:00:06 ifplugd
 1795 ?        00:00:01 ifplugd
 1797 ?        00:00:01 ifplugd
 1800 ?        00:00:00 wpa_supplicant
 1877 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
 2246 ?        00:00:00 rsyslogd
 2248 ?        00:00:00 thd
 2296 ?        00:00:00 cron
 2326 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon
 2393 ?        00:00:01 ntpd
 2422 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2513 tty1     00:00:00 getty
 2514 tty2     00:00:00 getty
 2515 tty3     00:00:00 getty
 2516 tty4     00:00:00 getty
 2517 tty5     00:00:00 getty
 2518 tty6     00:00:00 getty
 2519 ?        00:00:00 getty
 2520 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2524 ?        00:00:04 sshd
 2525 pts/0    00:00:02 bash
 2545 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2549 ?        00:00:39 sshd
 2550 ?        00:00:13 sftp-server
 2551 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2555 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2556 pts/1    00:00:01 bash
 2583 ?        00:00:00 sshd
 2587 ?        00:00:03 sshd
 2588 pts/2    00:00:01 bash
 4707 pts/2    00:02:56 watch
 8843 ?        00:00:06 kworker/u2:0
11547 ?        00:00:04 kworker/u2:1
12448 ?        00:00:03 kworker/u2:4
13186 ?        00:00:03 kworker/u2:2
13295 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo
13296 pts/0    00:01:09 a.out
13690 ?        00:00:01 kworker/u2:3
14083 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

This is what my data stream looks like, you can spot the bit where the SPI reads were delayed:

[image: The data stream, you can see missing data for about half a cycle around sample 3850]

You may of course want a look at my code. I have tried different buffer sizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>

#include "frdSPI.h"
#include "frdBuffer.h"

#define TRIGGERVAL 50

#define BUFF_SIZE 32

int main(void){

    unsigned char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
    int i, sample, channel = 0 , triggerdifference, oldsample, qtytowriteout = 0;
    unsigned long int samplenumber=0;
    unsigned long int differencenumber=0;

    FILE *fp;
    char filename[100];

    struct timeb recordtime;


    // Following is test code to see how to make filename and use it to write a file.
    ftime( &recordtime );
    sprintf( filename, "/frd/data/%ld%03ld.startup", recordtime.time, recordtime.millitm);

    fp = fopen( filename ,"w" );
    fprintf( fp, "test and more %lu", samplenumber);
    fclose(fp);



    if ( wiringPiSPISetup (channel, 500000) < 0){
        fprintf (stderr, "SPI Setup failed! Check module is loaded and run app as root.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(1){
        wiringPiSPIDataRW ( channel, &buffer, BUFF_SIZE );

        for(i=0; i<BUFF_SIZE; i++){
            sample=parseSPIDataStream(buffer[i]);
            if( sample > -1 ){
                samplenumber++;
                oldsample = circularbufferreadwrite( sample );

                if( calculateDifferenceValue(sample, &triggerdifference))
                {
                    differencenumber++;
                    if( triggerdifference > TRIGGERVAL || triggerdifference < (-1 * TRIGGERVAL) ){
                        //printf("%d \n", triggerdifference);
                        if( qtytowriteout == 0 )
                        {
                            ftime( &recordtime );
                            sprintf( filename, "/tmp/%ld%03ld.csv", recordtime.time, recordtime.millitm);
                            fp = fopen(filename,"w");
                            samplenumber=0;
                        }
                        if( qtytowriteout < 4000 )
                            qtytowriteout = qtytowriteout + 12800;
                    }
                }

                if( qtytowriteout && (fp!=(FILE *)NULL))
                {
                    //printf("%lu,%d\n", samplenumber, oldsample);
                    fprintf(fp, "%lu,%d\n", samplenumber, oldsample);
                    qtytowriteout--;
                    if( qtytowriteout == 0 ){
                        fclose(fp);
                        printf("\b");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions in advance.

EDIT
I just ran dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null as well, to take up some CPU time, and this has made the problems significantly worse, so I think I am on the right track, but I could do with some pointers as to how to fix it. Here is a graph of the data when using more CPU time:

[image]

A comment below queried parseSPIDataStream, so I've included it here:

```
int parseSPIDataStream( char databyte ){

    static int state=0;
    static int result=0;
    static int ignorebytes=10;
    static int synced=FALSE;

    if( ignorebytes==0 )
    {

        switch( databyte )
        {
            case 0X7E:          //0x7E Filler and sync
                state=0;
                synced=TRUE;
                return(-1);

            case 0x7D:          //Next Char is escaped
                state=2;
                return(-1);

            default:
                break;
        }

        switch( state )
        {
            case 0:         //High Byte of result
                result = 256 * databyte;
                state=1;
                return(-1);

            case 1:         //Low byte of result
                result = result + databyte;
                state=0;
                if( synced )
                    return(result);
                else
                    return(-1);

            case 2:         //Escaped Low Byte
                result = result + 0x20 + databyte;
                state=0;
                if( synced )
                    return(result);
                else
                    return(-1);

            default:            //There is an error!!!
                return(-2);
        }

    }else{
        ignorebytes--;
        return(-3);
    }

}
```

Comment: regarding this statement: `if( triggerdifference > TRIGGERVAL | triggerdifference < (-1 * TRIGGERVAL) )` the single `|` is a boolean OR.  What you really want is  a logical OR `||`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `sprintf( filename,
            "/frd/data/%ld%03ld.startup",
            recordtime.time,
            recordtime.millitm);` and `char filename[20];`  the array `filename` is not long enough to hold all the characters being  written into it by the call to `sprintf()`  This buffer overrun results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249. I appreciate your very insightful comments, and will modify the code accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: the variable `channel` is not initialized.  so using that uninitialized value in your posted code results in undefined behavior.   There are several other problems with the posted code.

Comment: regarding: `sample=parseSPIDataStream(buffer[i]);`  this can only see a single byte, so what is `parseSPIDataStream()` expected to accomplish?

Comment: the posted code is trying to include the header file: `time.h` and the header file: `sys/timeb.h` twice!

Comment: there is nothing in the posted code that uses any of the contents of the header file: `math.h`.   It is poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Similar considerations exist for the header file: `stdint.h`

Comment: parseSPIDataStream uses a state machine to return samples from the data stream. I have modified code in edit to take notice of your suggestions.

Comment: Ive added the code for parseSPIDataStream to give an idea to what it does. It will ignore 0x7E in the stream - as the raspberry pi is master and may ask for more data than available, the PIC just sends 0x7E in that case when its buffer is empty. 0x7D is used as an escape code to allow 0x7E and 0x7D by using 0x5E and 0x5D respectively in the data stream.

Comment: Also cross-posted on [raspberrypi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/70441/32014). (as an aside, there is an `snprintf()` to limit buf oflo).

Comment: I looked at the code for `parseSPIDataStream()` for clarity, the variable `state` would be better as an instance of an enum and that enum contain meaningful names for 0, 1, 2.  Such meaningful names would make the code much easier to understand,  The variable `ignorebytes` ignores the first 10 bytes (of the 20 byte parameter buffer)  of the very first I/O but does not ignore any after that. Please state why ignoring the first 10 bytes.

Comment: how does the code know that the call to: `wiringPiSPIDataRW()` input exactly 20 bytes?  if it inputs less than 20 bytes, the whole algorithm fails.

Comment: regarding: `result = result + 0x20 + databyte;`  this uses the prior value in result, but there is nothing determining that such a prior value is valid.  the sum of `result +0x20 +databyte could easily be a negative value.  Then the caller, in main(), would see a value less than 0 and ignore that value.   Suggest passing the address of a second parameter and only using the returned value from: `parseSPIDataStream()` for a success/fail check (I.E don't use the single returned value for both a status and a data byte)

Comment: the first time through the while() loop in `main(), the variable: `triggerdifference` is not initialized when the function: `calculateDifferenceValue()` is called.  BTW: what is that function comparing?

Comment: this `if()` statement: `if( triggerdifference > TRIGGERVAL
                    || triggerdifference < (-1 * TRIGGERVAL) )` seems to be trying to filter out data that has changed less than +/-50.  That could be only of the reasons that it 'seems' to miss some data samples

Comment: this statement: `oldsample = circularbufferreadwrite( sample );` seems to be adding quite a delay in the writing of the data, depending on how large that circular buffer is.  This also results in the data being written being out of sync with the `samplenumber` that is written with the `oldsample`

Comment: this `if()` statement: `if( qtytowriteout < 4000 )
                            qtytowriteout = qtytowriteout + 12800;` means that `qtytowriteout` will never be 0 after the first valid sample is read/processed

Comment: the variable: `differencenumber` is initialized and incremented, but never used nor displayed, etc.  Is it really needed?

Comment: Thanks again user3629249 for such useful feedback. Some answers to your questions:
"how does the code know that the call to: wiringPiSPIDataRW() input exactly 20 bytes? if it inputs less than 20 bytes, the whole algorithm fails." - the SPI slave device will continue to send data when required - if it has no data from a circular buffer to send, then it will send 0x7E as 'filler'

Comment: regarding: result = result + 0x20 + databyte; this uses the prior value in result, but there is nothing determining that such a prior value is valid.:
The SPI data has a 10bit A/D value, the High and Low byte are atomic, i.e. they are never separated, and always positive, as A/D can only be 0 to 1024.

Comment: "this if() statement: if( triggerdifference > TRIGGERVAL || triggerdifference < (-1 * TRIGGERVAL) ) seems to be trying to filter out data that has changed less than +/-50. That could be only of the reasons that it 'seems' to miss some data samples"

Yes, this triggers when there is something interesting in the data stream, like a small change in the RMS voltage that is being recorded. But when triggered, this code can only increase the number of samples to be written in an already active file, or start a new file, using the time as a file name.

Comment: "this statement: oldsample = circularbufferreadwrite( sample ); seems to be adding quite a delay in the writing of the data, depending on how large that circular buffer is. This also results in the data being written being out of sync with the samplenumber that is written with the oldsample –"

The buffer is so that there are a number of samples written to the record file before the triggering event, so we can see what the voltage looked like before the change. This is by design.

Comment: "the variable: differencenumber is initialized and incremented, but never used nor displayed, etc. Is it really needed?"

Good spot user3629249. this was a number I used during development debugging, and have since removed some of the debug code. I will remove it soon.

Thank you very much for your input, This is my first project and you are showing me a lot of great things. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Much appreciation to @user3629249